# Algorithm for picking brightest/most diverse image from a group?

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing

I have 100 images extracted from a video to use as a thumbnail in a gallery. My C# application needs to **pick which one is the most "interesting"** - or which one will entice the user to view the video after seeing the thumbnail.

Obviously some are more exciting than others; a black frame isn't exciting, neither is a pure white frame. Thus far I've come up (arbitrarily) with the following factors for what makes an image "stand-out" in a group.

- Should have a high level of **brightness**, but not totally white. Maybe averaging a brightness of 50% - 75% on a scale from black to white.
- Should have a **diverse set of colors**. Assuming this can be measured, images with the widest range of colors should stand out in the group.

How can these factors be calculated? Any other improvements that could pick the best image in a group?

Comment: Not really related, but is brightness the only criteria for determining that a picture is "interesting"? Actually, isn't interest closely related to personal taste and/or the context of the pictures?

Comment: @Ricardo - Certainly there are other factors... but when a machine has to pick (in the absence of user data), context and personal taste can't be factors.

Answer (score 4):

You also want the thumbnail to be representative of the video.  Try this:  Create N candidate thumbnails (evenly spaced in the video), create an average thumbnail by averaging the candidates, and then select the actual thumbnail that is closest to the average.

Comment: This is a good idea, but might break down for videos that contain visually diverse scenes.

Comment: Videos in which the best candidate is not particularly close to the average can be easily flagged for thumbnailing by some other method, like by-hand or middle-of-video.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Video Tapestries](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/gfx/pubs/Barnes_2010_VTW/index.php) paper from SIGGRAPH 2010. Obviously this is *complete* overkill for your project, but look over the previous work section. Hopefully will give you an idea about how you might go about deciding what material is interesting and representative.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this page to transform RGB to HSL(Hue, Saturation, Luminance):

http://130.113.54.154/~monger/hsl-rgb.html[enter link description here](http://130.113.54.154/~monger/hsl-rgb.html)

I haven't tried those equations, but I believe they will give a decent estimate without being too computationally intensive.  There is plenty of information out there on how to convert RGB to HSL if those don't work well.

Once you have done that, Luminance represents "Brightness."  Hue and Saturation together would represent the "Color."  Hue is the tint (is this a green or a red), while saturation is the intensity of the hue.

To determine the brightness of a picture, just look at it's Luminance (L) value.

To determine the color "range", as a first attempt I would do something like computing the vector sum of the Hue and Saturation.  This should give you a "distance away from white."  Something like:

```
Color Strength = Sqrt(Hue^2 + Saturation^2)
```

Find the two pixels with the min and max color strength, then subtract them to get a rough measure of how diverse the colors are.

You probably want to subsample each image, in other words, only calculate the HSL for a small amount of pixels from each image.  You will have to play around with what samples to calculate.  It may be best to take something like an 8x8 block from the center and each corner, calculate the average HSL for those blocks, then use them in your calculations.

I haven't actually tried any of this just have some remedial background in color spaces, so hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using your proposed method, you can collect statistics on the [Hue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) and brightness of each pixel, then calculate the mean and [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of each.  A higher stdev represents more diversity.